# Vue - Populate table with Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

Im trying to populate table with axios and vue, like this:

```
    <div class="container  h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>First</th>
                        <th>Last</th>
                        <th>Handle</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="user in users">
                        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var users;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(function (response) {
            users = response['data'];
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
</script>
```

The problem is that  {{user.name}} returns '{{user.name}}' , doesn´t show real data. Anybody know how can I use vue to show array data in a table?

**UPDATE**

I updated with this code but view still empty. If i return this.users in the script return a object with values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Tabla</title>
        <style>
            body,
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="tabla">
            <div class="container  h-100">
                <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover text-center">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="user in users">
                                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                                <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#tabla',
            data: {
                users: [],
            },
            created: function () {
                this.load();
            },
            methods: {
                load: function () {
                    axios
                        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            this.users = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                }
            }
        })
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesnt look like a vue component? Can we get a runnable snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Issue is with `this` inside your `axios api` callback.

This is not the right place to explain `this` very explanatory.

In simple context - `this` is the object that the `function` is the property of.
And In your case `this` get `window` object as you are using `function` which is not `lexically` scoped. To make it `lexically` scoped Use `ES6 Arrow fn`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        users: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
      axios
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {
          this.users = response.data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <table>
      <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>First</th>
                        <th>Last</th>
                        <th>Handle</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.email">
                        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You need to create `vue instance` which binds your `html` to it.

Let say you have `html` which has a `id = app`

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Now if you want this piece of html to use `vue`, you need to bind it.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', // This property el binds the container #app
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!' // here you create your data values you want to use
  }
})
```

However I would suggest you to look through `vue` awesome documentation before using it - [Vue JS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/)

Comment: Hey @ElHombreSinNombre Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't define `users` in a vue instance. You should create a vue instance and define `users` in the `data` part.

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    // Paste all of your html in here
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      users: []
    },
    mounted: function() {
      axios
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(function (response) {
          this.users = response['data'];
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: It´s correct but table return empty, something is wrong when print values :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly initiated Vue ?

Take a look at this official documentation.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html

If you have initiated the Vue in other file and this is only component definition,
you should still need to follow the component definition.
And call the Axios inside mount lifecycle and define users as data or computed.